# Get addresses that have my token and the amount

Tags: solidity, tokens

How can I find out what addresses my token has and how much is solid?
I thought of creating an array with the addresses like this would go through, but this array can grow to infinity and cost me a big gas.
My idea would be to get all the wallets that have my token with the amount of it.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be through **[events](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/contracts.html#events)**:

1. You can emit an event whenever there is a transfer from/to your token smart contract from/to an external account.
2. Afterwards, you can retrieve all the related events off-chain without any cost

Any other alternative on-chain might have significant gas fees.

Comment: Cool, but how can I recover events?

Comment: You can use web3.js or ethers.js to retrieve the events. For instance: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-subscribe.html